# Where can I find a list of prime numbers with 17-20 digits?

Tags: prime-numbers

I see many (non cryptographic) hashes use prime numbers. Where can I find a list of primes that have 17-20digits? An unsigned 64 has 20digits (with the top 2 being 18) so I was thinking 19 digits would all fit and many 20 digits would be usable

Comment: You may get a better response on cryptography stack exchange.

Comment: Non need to refer to other pages. Just search. [Here](https://primes.utm.edu/curios/index.php?start=17&stop=22) for example.

Comment: @DietrichBurde why didn't you make it an answer? TYVM tho :)

Comment: Estimating the number of primes with 17...20 decimals is $$\pi(10^{20})-\pi(10^{17})\approx 2.17\cdot10^{18}$$so that you won't find lists that are anywhere near to being complete. So you probably have additional criteria.  Apart from that, the numbers are small enough that one can find such numbers easily, e.g. using Sage or similar (freely available) programming languages.

Comment: If you need primes for crypto purposes, the way to do it would be to generate random integers, until you get a prime one. Primarity testing is cheap, and expected number of trials is ~linear in number of bits (by the Prime Number Theorem).